# How can i extract a TextField from a pdf using iText?

Tags: java, itext, textfield

I need extract a TextField from PDF using iText.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf.getAbsolutePath());

AcroFields form = reader.getAcroFields();
Map<String, Item> fields = form.getFields();

for(Entry<String, Item> entry : fields.entrySet()){
    String field_name = entry.getKey();

    int field_type = form.getFieldType(field_name);
    List<FieldPosition> fieldPosition = form.getFieldPositions(field_name);

    Rectangle position = fieldPosition.get(0).position;

    float left   = position.getLeft();
    float top    = position.getTop();
    float width  = position.getWidth();
    float height = position.getHeight();

    int load_page = fieldPosition.get(0).page;


    /**
    In this point I need to extract maxlength and options of filed.
    This information are stored in a TextField object and i can read with the methods TextField.getMaxCharacterLength() and TextField.getOptions().
    **/
}

reader.close();
```

The Text Field object contains the information which I need, that is maxlength and options with the methods TextField.getMaxCharacterLength() and TextField.getOptions().

There is another solution for extract these information?

Comment: *There is another solution for extract these information?* - why are you trying to find another solution? What is inappropriate about the solution you have?

Comment: Please add the RESOLVED part as an answer and accept it...

Answer (score 0):

Resolved using PdfDictionary

```
Item field = entry.getValue();

PdfDictionary dict = field.getMerged(0);

int maxLength = dict.getAsNumber(PdfName.MAXLEN).intValue();
int ff = dict.getAsNumber(PdfName.FF).intValue();
```

ff var contains a number that indicate te type of field

There is the code to check if field is comb

```
if((ff & BaseField.COMB) > 0)
```